# Node.js app with NForce; retrieving records from salesforce on startup

Tags: rest, node.js, nforce

I am attempting to modify this code:

https://github.com/jeffdonthemic/node-streaming-socketio/blob/master/app.js

So that as well as setting up the streaming, on startup it also performs a query to retrieve some records which are displayed to the user. I am attempting to place code like so:

```
var q = 'SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, BillingCity FROM Account';

sfdc.query({ query: q }, function(err, resp){

  if(!err && resp.records) {

    // do something with record, display to client
  }
});
```

After the connection and ouath have been set up, however, I am unsure where to place that code in the lifecycle of the main application (app.js). Also, I am unsure how to pass this record once I have it so that it can be displayed on the client side. I keep getting this error when placing this code at various places in app.js:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'instance_url' of undefined
```

Comment: I think the problem is the code is over 2 years old and there have been alot of changes to nforce. I'm upgrading the code now and will push it as soon as i can.

Comment: OK.. I've updated the code in this repo so you may want pull it again. Much less code now with the update to nforce. Also, I'm not sure if you actually need to use the streaming api or are just trying to CRUD records from salesforce. You may also want to check out this repo for some basic code: https://github.com/jeffdonthemic/node-nforce-demo.

Comment: @JeffDouglas awesome, thanks! and actually, I need my app to do both :) i'll check out the other repo

Comment: @JeffDouglas I'm still getting the same error, I'm placing a query after where you commented ' // add any logic to perform after login '. Is that the correct place? I'm thinking my callback url might not be correct in the remote app, should it still be set to localhost?

Comment: Yes! Your callback in Salesforce should be something like http://localhost:3000 or whatever port you are using. Also, make sure your password contains your security token in the app.

Comment: @JeffDouglas all those settings were correct, so I was still stumped. I switched the mode from 'multi' to 'single' though, and now it works perfectly! Any idea why?

Comment: Check out the docs on how the oauth token is stored.

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause would be that you are querying before the oauth callback is over.

Make sure you query after successful callback of authenticate()

org.authenticate(username:'',password:'' ,function(err,resp){

if(!err)
   //query here
})

//query here will give the error!